# Не запускается JAR файл

Tags: java, javafx

Написал JavaFX приложение, в настройках проекта настроил Artifacts, и сделал Build Artifacts. Jar Файл создался, но не запускается. В чем может быть причина?

Вот содержимое Main класса

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //Создаем загрузчик для файла fxml
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

        //Загружаем fxml файл
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/phonesapp/fxml/mainScene.fxml"));
        Parent fxmlMain = fxmlLoader.load();

        //получаем контроллер для сцены mainScene вызывая метод getController()
        MainController mainController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        //Вызываем метод setMainStage контроллера MainController, для того чтобы установить для него подмостки (Stage)
        mainController.setMainStage(primaryStage);

        //Для подмостков указываем заголовок, размеры и устанавливаем в качестве сцены окно fxmlMain
        primaryStage.setTitle("Программа для просмотра и редактирования телефонов");
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(800);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(500);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlMain));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Из Idea все нормально запускается и можно работать.

Вот что вышло при попытке запустить из командной строки

> C:\jar>java -jar PhonesApp.jar Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in
>   Application start method
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
>   file:/C:/jar/PhonesApp.jar!/phonesapp/fxml/mainScene.fxml
>
> ```
>     at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown
> ```
>
> Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
>           at phonesapp.start.Main.start(Main.java:19)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method)
>           at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown
>   Source)
>           ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           ... 13 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row
>           at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
>           at phonesapp.controllers.MainController.selectsSceneLoader(MainController.java:195)
>           at phonesapp.controllers.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:120)
>           ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 37 more Exception running application phonesapp.start.Main
>
> C:\jar>

Comment: что значит "не запускается" ?

Comment: Ну кликаю на jar файл не открывается приложение

Comment: а почему оно должно открыться?

Comment: А почему не должно?

Comment: потому, что у вас не настроен запуски приложений при открытии файлов с типом .jar

Comment: А как это настроить и где?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте запустить из командной строки, примерно так `java -jar file.jar`

Comment: не уверен, что получится вообще сделать запуск по двойному клику. Я обычно делал ярлык, в котором так запускался файл

Comment: Да, покажите вывод консоли. Скорее всего, у вас нет манифест файла, либо в нем не задан главный класс

Comment: Главный класс я задал. Вот что в манифесте Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: phonesapp.start.Main

Comment: Добавил в вопрос, то что вышло при попытке запустить из командной строки

Comment: Разобрался. Оказывается я выбирал в Artifacts просто JAR, а нужно было JavaFX Application